# How to respond to user deletion from database in react?

Tags: api, reactjs, redux

I have an app that have login form and redirects you to your profile page. On this profile page I want to somehow respond when user gets deleted from database. At this moment I can only respond if my app requests user info from db and gets 401. This situation occurs only if I go to Profile info page. But how can I respond immediately? Is it possible without rewriting whole app logic?

Comment: IMO the login functionality shouldn't work anymore if the user is deleted from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your user info check to the login form right before you redirect to the profile page. Make the same request to get user info and if you get a 401 you can immediately show an error and even prevent the page from routing to the profile page when you know the user doesn't exist.